# Уставиться — НА что или ВО что?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, выбор-варианта

Предложение из книги Людмилы Мартовой [«Первый шаг к мечте»](https://books.google.ee/books?id=zihgDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT145&lpg=PT145&dq=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%20%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=0VnPB7abFf&sig=ACfU3U3b-SbkCZnfRywNHz7NxSigyCU98A&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiOhqjCturnAhUJyKYKHYh8AyYQ6AEwAHoECAoQAg#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%20%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0&f=false).

> Полная энтузиазма Нина прошествовала в прихожую, решительно отодвинула левую зеркальную дверцу шкафа и **уставилась в его содержимое**.

Если бы я была автором этого предложения, то чисто интуитивно выбрала бы предлог **на**: уставилась (на что?) **на** его содержимое.
Подскажите, а какой все-таки предлог правильно использовать в этом контексте — **на** или **в**?

Answer (score 3):

Словари допускают вариант "*уставиться **в***" (Ушаков: *уставиться глазами в лицо*), но в **данном контексте** употребление предлога "в", на мой взгляд, **не имеет достаточных оснований**.
Если обратиться к устойчивым выражениям "уставленности" (*взглядом*; есть ещё значение "упереться во что-либо" — осёл у Крылова и пр.) во что-то (**в землю**, **в небо**, **в одну точку**), можно заметить, что в этих случаях речь идёт о ***направленности*** взгляда куда-либо, а не о ***разглядывании*** чего-либо (вглядывании во что-либо, кого-либо). Такой взгляд с позиции наблюдателя неподвижен, со стороны неясно, что именно видится уставившемуся **в** обозначенном направлении (или даже "в замочную скважину"): возможно даже, что ничего — он просто о чём-то задумался.
С предлогом же **на** всегда присутствует ***истинный объект внимания*** смотрящего (уставиться **на** кого-то, **на** что-то), что и имеет место в предложенном примере (персонаж удивленно смотрит **на** то, что открылось взгляду).

Comment: Тоже так считаю.

Comment: @Alex_ander Извините, прошляпила Ваш интересный ответ. Теперь отметила. Подправила (думаю, что с разделением на абзацы, информация лучше воспринимается. Не нравится — откатите).

Answer (score 2):

Судя по [примерам](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B2), так часто говорят. Можно даже уставиться в кого-то.

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

> *И тут вдруг его глаза округлились и стали совершенно безумными, и он уставился в спинку кресла.* [М. А. Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита, часть 1 (1929-1940)]
>
> *Лейтенант Уимбли взглянул на карандашные каракули и через минуту уставился в лицо подчиненного с необычайным выражением.* [Б. А. Лавренев. Крушение республики Итль (1925)]
>
> *― Ну! ― вдруг злобно закричал на сына издали отец и уставился в него поверх очков остановившимися глазами.* [Н. Никандров. Проклятые зажигалки (1920-1929)]

К сожалению, не смог выяснить, совершенно они взаимозаменяемы или есть нюансы в употреблении этих предлогов. Но я тоже привык к тому, что уставиться можно ***на*** кого-то. В вашем случае я бы, возможно, тоже сказал в первый момент с *на,* не знаю точно, но сейчас, посмотрев на другие примеры и привыкнув к этому, уже воспринимаю вариант из книжки вполне нормально. Почему-то хочется употребить *на,* если его содержимое разложено в один слой, а если какие-то предметы загорожены другими, выбрал бы *в.*

А вообще, вопрос очень интересный. Странно, что сразу не догадался за него проголосовать.

И ещё мне кажется, что если *кто-то уставился **во что-то**,* он его пристально разглядывает (отбрасываю этот смысл — убедился на примерах, что этого не имеют в виду) или просто направил взгляд на какой-то предмет, как отметил Alex_ander (об этом говорится во 2-м значении на Грамоте), а если *уставился **на что-то**,* то скорее не может понять, что перед собой видит, недоумевает, что же это такое. В том числе когда ожидал увидеть что-то другое.

Answer (score 1):

Предлог В обозначает чёткую фиксацию действия (взгляда). Обычно это ступор, когда не знает, что делать дальше, или задумался.
*Уставился **в** одну точку.* || Не "на".

"На" более нейтрально обозначает объект взгляда без чёткой фиксации. Обычно это рассматривание чего-то, представляющего интерес. Поэтому если про человека, то говорят "на", его не выбирают как точку для взгляда, а рассматривают. Предмет же удобнее выбрать как точку. Это используется при медитации.

Comment: Добрый день!  Не хотите ли вы уделить форуму хотя бы еще немного вашего внимания, а то вас здесь не хватает.  Отвечающих немного,  а новые участники не задерживаются. Вы же, как мне кажется, произвели  на всех хорошее впечатление  (по крайней мере, на меня уж точно).

Comment: Добрый день. На тот момент открывал для себя новое, отвечая на вопросы. С того времени мой уровень стал гораздо выше, и нового для себя уже не вижу (темы часто повторяются). Немного внимания - можно: если какие-то вопросы (в частности, ваши вопросы без ответов) всё ещё интересуют, можете скинуть их цифровые индексы (так короче, чтоб не кидать ссылки целиком).

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл это место в книге и посмотрел контекст. Попытался представить себе образно происходящую сценку. Сразу же приходит в голову устойчивое выражение **впериться взглядом**. Именно это делает Нина, смотря на содержимое шкафа (она не рассматривает содержимое, а решительно нацелена на поиск нужного предмета, который, вопреки ожиданиям, обнаруживается не сразу). Считаю употребление предлога "в" в данном случае уместным.

Answer (score 0):

Эти предлоги имеют большую вариативность употребления, чему способствует то, что они относятся к группе предлогов с большой функционально-грамматической омонимией. Им посвящено немало научных работ, в которых подчёркивается их зависимость от семантики. В.В. Виноградов: "В толковых словарях русского языка коллекционируются группы значений отдельных предлогов. Но все это лишь материал для грамматического исследования, требующий пересмотра" [Виноградов 1972: 518]. Предлог "на" может употребляться с двумя падежами: винительным (значение пути движения с оттенком достижения цели) и предложным (значение  места, местоположения). Правило говорит, что "открытое пространство – требует употребления предлога на, а закрытое, строго ограниченное – предлога в". Поэтому говорим "на Украине" и "в шкафу".

Comment: *Поэтому говорим "на Украине"* — В последнее время всё чаще встречаются люди, которые считают, что правильно говорить "на России", а не "в России". Теперь я понимаю их логику. Кстати, углубившись в странные пространные рассуждения, Вы забыли ответить на вопрос.